# Express get route not working, postman request times out after being stuck for a while

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Express app is not working with ger route as postman request get
stuck while fetching reponse for a while. Get route is present
with necessary request parser and app initialisation and setup.

```
const express = require('express')
const env = require('dotenv')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
//environment variables
env.config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT

app.use(cors)
app.use(bodyParser())

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.status(200).send('Hello World');
  })

app.post('/data',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.status(200).send(req.body)
})

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
console.log("Server is running on", PORT)
})
```

Express app is not working with ger route as postman request get
stuck while fetching reponse for a while. Get route is present
with necessary request parser and app initialisation and setup.

Comment: any error logs on server ? is your server crashed

Comment: @thelonglqd No error on server console.
localhost:2000/ , route i am hitting to expect hello world

Comment: Server is running on 2000

Comment: you can use `console.log` in this route to know it actually get there yet or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use app.use(cors());

I have checked the code on postman after this change and it is returning response as expected.

Comment: Thanks it worked with cors() correction in middleware

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `app.use(cors())`?

Because I think you are not applying the middleware